# Post call in Rest API

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, hubspot

I am trying to set up a Post call in Javascript to create a contact in my hubspot account.  I am new to Rest API and how this all works.  This is what the documentation says about doing so.

Required Parameters How to use  Description
HubSpot API Key -----   hapikey=X ---- Used in the request URL  The HubSpot API key for the portal that you're making the call for.

Contact JSON    -----Used in the request body-----  This is JSON that represents a contact that you're creating. This should be of the format seen below in the code sample given.

Email Address-----  Used in the request body-----   Please note that Email Address is a required part of the JSON that you POST to HubSpot when creating a new contact.
Optional Parameters How to use  Description

None    None    No optional parameters for this method.

Example URL to POST to:  https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/?hapikey=demo

I get the example and I can make get calls using the hapikey=demo.  What I don't understand is the Used in the Request Body.  What does that fully mean and how do I implement it.  I can't find any documentation on to actually load the JSON onto the post call.

Here is what I have

```
var testContact = '{"properties":['+
                '{"property":"email","value":"testing@hubspot.com"},'+
                '{"property":"firstname","value":"Peter"},'+
                '{"property":"lastname","value":"xxxxx"}]}';

                var test = JSON.parse(testContact);
                //alert(test.properties[1].value);
                //console.log(test.properties[1].firstname);

                $.post("https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/?hapikey=demo&contact=" + testContact + "&email=" + test.properties[0].value,function(result){
                console.log(result);
                });
```

I keep getting a bad request from the server so it must be connecting and I am setting up the info wrong.

UPDATE

So i un "stringified it" and what is interesting when i try and pass that i just get an object and not the whole string.

https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/?hapikey=3fd8a881-2859-4c85-bec8-690bd989a889&contact=[object%20Object]&email=testingapis@hubspot.com

```
var testContact = {
                "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "email",
                    "value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
                },
                {
                    "property": "firstname",
                    "value": "Adrian"
                },
                {
                    "property": "lastname",
                    "value": "Mott"
                }]};


                $.post("https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/?hapikey=3fd8a881-2859-4c85-bec8-690bd989a889&contact=" + testContact + "&email=" + testContact.properties[0].value,function(result){
                console.log(result);
                });
```

Comment: have you heard of PostMan? its a pretty cool free app that lets you do a lot of API stuff, I suggest you try it... https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Yea I actually did stumble across this earlier today but I can't seem to make any Post calls with it only get calls.  I am not sure how to format the JSON properly.  it does seem like a cool app though

Comment: I can tell your JSON object has issues, try this: see what postman returns from the get, you need to send that same format back to hubspot but with the proper values..., you're close man...

Comment: I was trying to follow the API documentation which is this

{
            "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "email",
                    "value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
                },
                {
                    "property": "firstname",
                    "value": "Adrian"
                },
                {
                    "property": "lastname",
                    "value": "Mott"
                }...........

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect, no need to "stringify" and then parse it.... just send an object like so:

I know you have seen this page: http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/create_contact

try to copy exactly the object they have on that page, do not modify it other than taking off the properties you dont need to send...

```
{
            "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "email",
                    "value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
                },
                {
                    "property": "phone",
                    "value": "555-122-2323"
                },
                {
                    "property": "address",
                    "value": "25 First Street"
                },
                {
                    "property": "city",
                    "value": "Cambridge"
                },
                {
                    "property": "state",
                    "value": "MA"
                },
                {
                    "property": "zip",
                    "value": "02139"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: so using this gives me a syntax error.  is having the contact= and email= even right? I am just guessing at that. 

var testContact = {
    "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "email",
                    "value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
                },
                {
                    "property": "firstname",
                    "value": "Adrian"
                },
                {
                    "property": "lastname",
                    "value": "Mott"
                }]};
    
    var test = JSON.parse(testContact);

Comment: Yes the link you posted was what I had originally posted above.  My issue is it doesn't share how to properly format email and contact.  For the key it shows you in the example.  For all i know the contact= and email= could be wrong.

Comment: I can't say I understand this but I just got this to work.

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/?hapikey=demo",
      processData: false,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(testContact),
      success: function(r) {}

     });